# \edef not working with \@author

Tags: document-classes, etoolbox

I am writing a custom `documentclass` and I would like to split `\@author` on `\and` (which I redefine to `\unskip,`) to use with `etoolbox` `\docsvlist`:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myarticle}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[11pt, titlepage]{article}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\and}{\unskip,}

\edef\theauthor{\@author}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{##1\\}
\textit{\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1}}
}

\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
\mycommand{\theauthor{}}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
}

\endinput
```

If used like this:

```latex
\documentclass{myarticle}

\author{Me \and You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I would like each author in a separate line, but that does not work. I simply get:

[image]

- If I do not `\edef` and replace `\theauthor` by `\@author`, I get "Me,You" (the `docsvlist` does not work).
- If I replace the `\edef` by `\edef\theauthor{Me \and You}` it works.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Note that `\edef\theauthor{\@author}` is executed when the class is loaded and therefore uses the original definition of `\@author`, which is a LaTeX warning or something similar (don't remember exactly). Your `\theauthor` never gets to see the content of `\author`.

Comment: @campa Thanks, makes sense. Moving the `\edef` within the `\renewcommand` solves it!

Comment: Never use \edef with a command like \@author where you have no control over the content. Use \protected@edef instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Comment: You might want to take a look to see how authors are handled in `amsart.cls` or `amsbook.cls`; they are input separately, and a `\contributor` possibility is also provided for, e.g., someone who writes just a section,